# Why parent class ref to child class object cannot access child class variable?

Tags: java

> Parent Class

```
 class Parent
        {
            int a = 10 ;
            int b = 20 ;
            int c = 50 ;

            public void display(){
                System.out.println("In Parent Class");
            }
        }
```

> Child Class

```
    public class Child extends Parent{

        int c = 30 ;
        int d = 40 ;

        public void display(){
            System.out.println("In Child Class");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
```

> Parent class ref referring to child class object.

```
            Parent p = new Child();
```

> ***Calls Parent Class variable***

```
            System.out.println(p.c);
```

> Calls child class method

```
            p.display();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `ParentChildExample` class?

Comment: You haven't defined `ParentChildExample`

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned, your ``p`` variable is of the type ``Parent``. Since ``Parent`` has no field ``c``, it won't work. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

it seemed that you want to access child filed variable **c** through parent reference.

```
Parent p = new Child();
System.out.println(p.c);
```

it will output the **filed c** of **Parent**, you cant access **c** of **Child** through parent reference because through `p` is an instance of `child`, but it is accessed through `Parent` reference and *Parent reference* cant reach the **c** of child.

and if you want to print **c** of **Child**. You should downTypeCast as below:

```
Child child = (Child)(p);
System.out.println(child.c);
```

it will print the **c** of **child**.

Comment: Thanks for the help but can you explain why we can't access child variable just like child method without downTypeCast

Comment: @user4886675  through p is instance of child, **but** it is accessed through *Parent reference* and *Parent reference* cant reach the *c* of child.